# how to compute a new column based on the values of other columns in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say my data frame contains these data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['l1','l2','l1','l2','l1','l2'],
                       'b':['1','2','2','1','2','2']})
>>> df
    a       b
0  l1       1
1  l2       2
2  l1       2
3  l2       1
4  l1       2
5  l2       2
```

`l1` should correspond to `1` whereas `l2` should correspond to `2`. 
I'd like to create a new column '`c`' such that, for each row, `c = 1` if `a = l1` and `b = 1` (or `a = l2` and `b = 2`). If `a = l1` and `b = 2` (or `a = l2` and `b = 1`) then `c = 0`.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
  a         b   c
0  l1       1   1
1  l2       2   1
2  l1       2   0
3  l2       1   0
4  l1       2   0
5  l2       2   1
```

My data frame is very large so I'm really looking for the most efficient way to do this using pandas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': numpy.random.choice(['l1', 'l2'], 1000000),
                   'b': numpy.random.choice(['1', '2'], 1000000)})
```

A fast solution assuming only two distinct values:

```
%timeit df['c'] = ((df.a == 'l1') == (df.b == '1')).astype(int)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

@Viktor Kerkes:

```
%timeit df['c'] = (df.a.str[-1] == df.b).astype(int)
```

1 loops, best of 3: 412 ms per loop

@user1470788:

```
%timeit df['c'] = (((df['a'] == 'l1')&(df['b']=='1'))|((df['a'] == 'l2')&(df['b']=='2'))).astype(int)
```

1 loops, best of 3: 363 ms per loop

@herrfz

```
%timeit df['c'] = (df.a.apply(lambda x: x[1:])==df.b).astype(int)
```

1 loops, best of 3: 387 ms per loop

Comment: Interesting, however it your solution is significantly less general. What's interesting here is how bad `str[1]` methods compared to a simple lambda.

Comment: You did not test for when `(df.a == 'l2') == (df.b == '2')`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I assume the example input is complete, and `a` only has values `l1` or `l2` and `b` only `'1'` or `'2'`.   If `a != 'l1'`, it must be `'l2'`.

Comment: @user2716201:  I don't believe the OP's sentence "Let's say my data frame contains these data" supports that assumption.  I think you should to clearly call out that assumption in your answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: good point, updated description. But I would not be surprised if in the real data the values might be 'dog' and 'cat', in which case the substring solutions would break...  I would also like to point out that OP asked for the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the string methods.

```
df['c'] = (df.a.str[-1] == df.b).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

`df['c'] = (df.a.apply(lambda x: x[1:])==df.b).astype(int)`

Answer (score -1):

You can just use logical operators. I'm not sure why you're using strings of 1 and 2 rather than ints, but here's a solution.  The astype at the end converts it from boolean to 0's and 1's.

`df['c'] = (((df['a'] == 'l1')&(df['b']=='1'))|((df['a'] == 'l2')&(df['b']=='2'))).astype(int)`