# How to create new column and insert row values while iterating through pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I am trying to create a function that iterates through a pandas dataframe row by row. I want to create a new column based on row values of other columns. My original dataframe could look like this:

```
df:

   A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  2   2
```

Now I want to create a new column filled with the row values of Column A - Column B at each index position, so that the result looks like this:

```
 df:

       A   B   A-B
    0  1   2   -1
    1  3   4   -1
    2  2   2    0
```

the solution I have works, but only when I do NOT use it in a function:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print index
        df['A-B']=df['A']-df['B']
```

This gives me the desired output, but when I try to use it as a function, I get an error.

```
def test(x):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print index
        df['A-B']=df['A']-df['B']
    return df
df.apply(test)

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 3
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get it to work?

Comment: do you need only substract column from each other or it's just a simple example?

Comment: I actually really need just a new column containing the results of column A minus column B

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method works for column by default, change `axis` to 1 if you'd like through rows:

> **axis** : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> - 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column
> - 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row

```
df.apply(test, axis=1)
```

**EDIT**

I thought that you need to do something complex manupulation with each row. If you need just substract columns from each other:

```
df['A-B'] = df.A - df.B
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I still get the same error, though it seems to work anyway...

Comment: for me it works both ways with `axis=1` an `axis=0` what `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.17.0

Comment: @AntonProtopopov could this approach be used for constants as well? for example `my_df['Division by constant c'] = my_df.column_A / 4` ?

Answer (score 4):

Like indicated by Anton you should execute the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function with `axis=1` parameter. However it is  not necessary to then loop through the rows as you did in the function test, since 
the [`apply` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) mentions:

> Objects passed to functions are Series objects

So you could simplify the function to:

```
def test(x):
    x['A-B']=x['A']-x['B']
    return x
```

and then run:

```
df.apply(test,axis=1)
```

Note that in fact you named the parameter of test `x`, while not using `x` in the function `test` at all.

Finally I should comment that you can do column wise operations with pandas (i.e. without for loop) doing simply this:

```
df['A-B']=df['A']-df['B']
```

Also see:

- [how to compute a new column based on the values of other columns in pandas - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472634/how-to-compute-a-new-column-based-on-the-values-of-other-columns-in-pandas-pyt)
- [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that the creation of ne new column was possible without the for-loop!

Comment: Actually this is a new question. But, already asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472634/how-to-compute-a-new-column-based-on-the-values-of-other-columns-in-pandas-pyt

Comment: `df['A-B']=df['A']-df['B']` does not work if you want to pass anything from the right through an external function. For example `df['A-B'] = my_function(df['A'])` will not work. Instead you have to use this syntax: `df['A-B'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x.A), axis=1)`, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52854800/6793507